# Mejorar performance de una consulta

Tags: mysql

Me gustaria saber a nivel de rendimiento si hay forma de mejorar la siguiente query que pongo al final de este post.
Actualmente solo tengo 17 resultados:

```
select cpu,gpu from RPI02;

+--------+------+
| cpu    | gpu  |
+--------+------+
| 37.856 | 37.4 |
| 37.394 | 37.9 |
| 37.932 | 37.4 |
| 36.394 | 37.9 |
| 36.394 | 36.9 |
| 36.932 | 37.9 |
| 37.856 | 37.9 |
| 37.856 | 36.9 |
| 36.394 | 37.4 |
| 36.856 | 37.4 |
| 36.394 | 36.9 |
| 36.394 | 36.9 |
| 36.856 | 36.9 |
| 35.856 | 36.3 |
| 36.780 | 36.9 |
| 36.856 | 36.9 |
| 36.856 | 37.4 |
| 36.318 | 36.3 |
+--------+------+
```

y la siguiente query me muestra el numero total de valores junto con un calculo del valor máximo, mínimo y promedio

```
select count(*), 
    ROUND(MIN(cpu),1) AS "MIN(cpu)", 
    ROUND(MAX(cpu),1) AS "MAX(cpu)",
    ROUND(AVG(cpu),1) AS "AVG(cpu)",
    ROUND(MIN(gpu),1) AS "MIN(gpu)",
    ROUND(MAX(gpu),1) AS "MAX(gpu)",
    ROUND(AVG(gpu),1) AS "AVG(cpu)"
from RPI02
    order by time ASC;

+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| count(*) | MIN(cpu) | MAX(cpu) | AVG(cpu) | MIN(gpu) | MAX(gpu) | AVG(cpu) |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|       17 |     35.9 |     37.9 |     36.9 |     36.3 |     37.9 |     37.2 |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

En el momento que la BBDD empiece a tener muchos valores, (el proceso se ejecuta cada minuto), hay forma de que los datos sean indexados para que las búsquedas sean mas rápidas?
Que debería de hacer y mejorar?

La creación de la tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE RPI02 (
    time DATETIME,
    hostname VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    cpu VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    gpu VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE INDEX `time` (`time`)
);
```

Gracias!

Comment: No tienes ningún `where`, por lo que dudo que un índice sea útil en este caso ya que tu consulta es sobre el total de filas de la tabla. Por otra parte `order by time ASC` no tiene sentido en tu consulta. Saludos.

Comment: el ASC lo tenia para otra y lo he aprovechado. Pero hay forma de agilizar una busqueda o mas bien hacer el calculo de cada una de las filas?

Comment: La pregunta es ¿por qué necesitas todas las filas para hacer estos cálculos?

Comment: para poder saber la media, maxima y minima referente a todos los valores.

Comment: Te entiendo, pero en estadística se trabaja normalmente con muestras y no con la población completa. Si pudieras trabajar de esta forma podría proponerte hacer una selección aleatoria de casos y sobre eso aplicar estos estadísticos. Lamentablemente, sobre la totalidad de las filas, tarde o temprano la consulta se irá resintiendo en cuanto a performance y no hay índice que pueda resolver esto.